# Easy way to left join parent data to multiple left join child data

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Is there an easier way to left join parent data to multiple child left join data?

Table Structure:

```
Table1 {id, name, data1, data2, datax}
Table2 {id, table1_id, dataA, dataB, userid}
Table3 {id, table1_id, dataD, userid}
Table4 {id, table1_id, dataE, userid}
TableUsers {userid, username, name, email}
```

SQL Query:

```
select Table1.*, Table2.*,Table3.*,Table4.*
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table3 t3 on t3.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table4 t4 on t4.table1_id = t1.id
```

From here I want to replace the userid field with the actual user name and each table will have different data for userid so a simple left join  with TableUsers won't work since it will only take affect for the table it is set equal to.

I have thought about doing it with a sub query, but believe that would be extra slow:

```
select Table1.*,(select TableUser.name from TableUser where Table1.userid = TableUser.userid) as T1Name,
 Table2.*,(select TableUser.name from TableUser where Table2.userid = TableUser.userid) as T2Name,
Table3.*, (select TableUser.name from TableUser where Table3.userid = TableUser.userid) as T3Name,
Table4.*,(select TableUser.name from TableUser where Table1.userid = TableUser.userid) as T4Name
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table3 t3 on t3.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table4 t4 on t4.table1_id = t1.id
```

The point of this is to move from an SQL database to MongoDB. Perhaps I need to rethink this entire query...
Cheers,

Chip

Comment: Hey. Is Table2.userid = Table3.userid if Table2.table1_id = Table3.table1_id ?

Comment: Are data1,2,x,a,b,d,e all the same type? If so I'd be looking at a restructure.

Comment: The userid data in each table will be different. It is most likely that in 1 row the userid for table2 will be different from each other reference of userid. 

Also Data 1,2,x,a,etc are not the same type. Each table is a simplistic representation of our process tables. Each process will have its own data to be logged and the user who logged the data. I created a simply representation since my goal is to understand a better way to join joined data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "normal" way to do this would be to add additional joins:

```
select Table1.*, t1name.name, Table2.*, t2name.name, Table3.*, t3name.name,
       Table4.*, t4name.name
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table3 t3 on t3.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join Table4 t4 on t4.table1_id = t1.id
left outer join TableUser t1name on t1.userid = t1name.userid
left outer join TableUser t2name on t2.userid = t2name.userid
left outer join TableUser t3name on t3.userid = t3name.userid
left outer join TableUser t4name on t4.userid = t4name.userid;
```

If you have an indexon `TableUser(userid)` or `TableUser(userid, name)`, then the performance of the two methods should be about the same.

Comment: To further illustrate how little of a difference it makes, you could view the execution plan of the two queries. In SQL Server 2008, I run the two queries together in one batch, and the execution plan shows that, relative to the batch, the subquery select takes 49%, while the join after join query takes 51%, so theoretically, this means the subqueries are actually faster in this case. Note: I ran this over a very small set of data. Just try it in your database, and see for yourself.

Comment: I will use this, it seems more elegant than the sub-queries.